# golang reflection to initialise struct that satisfies an interface

Tags: go, reflection

Can I get rid of the switch with some sort of reflection? `brand` will **always** match the struct name

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Car interface {
    Move()
    SetModel()
}

type Ford struct {
    Model string
}

type Volkswagen struct {
    Model string
}

func (car *Ford) Move() {
    fmt.Println(car.Model + " is moving!")
}

func (car *Ford) SetModel() {
    car.Model = "Focus"
}

func (car *Volkswagen) Move() {
    fmt.Println(car.Model + " is moving!")
}

func (car *Volkswagen) SetModel() {
    car.Model = "Jetta"
}

func main() {
    var car Car

    brand := "Ford"

    switch brand {
    case "Ford":
        car = &Ford{}
    case "Volkswagen":
        car = &Volkswagen{}
    }
    car.SetModel()
    car.Move()
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214469/discussion-on-question-by-user3781074-golang-reflection-to-initialise-struct-tha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `reflect` to produce a type from only a string of its name, so probably want a map of type factories, but with as many cases as you've stated you need, you probably want to generate it programatically with `go generate`. It would work basically like so:

```
var constructors = map[string]func() Car{
    "Ford": func() Car{
        return &Ford{}
    },
    "Volkswagen": func() Car{
        return &Volkswagen{}
    },
}

// ...
car := constructors[brand]()
```